# No output being shown on the screen

Tags: java, bluej

Please see why there is being no output shown on the screen!
I am writing a program that could print "Happy Birthday" 10 times on the screen.
My program is:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Task_1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a;
        for(a=1;a>=10;a++)
            System.out.println("Happy Birthday");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for(a=1;a>=10;a++)` is wrong

it must be
 `for(a=1;a<=10;a++)`
 Your condition is not valid that is why you get nothing printed

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Task_1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            System.out.println("Happy Birthday"); // It'll be printed 10 times
    }
}
```

This should work, try it out.

Your `for` loop was saying: *if `a` is equal to or bigger than 10 then print "Happy Birthday"* which was returning false thus not printing anything and ending the loop.